# android viewpager2 page buton controller

Tags: android, android-viewpager

if the page is loaded, the button is active, if not, how can I do passive control?

What I want to do is, if the Viewpager Page is loaded, the button is active, if not, the Button is Passive. But I couldn't do any kind.
Is there anyone who can help?

If viewpager2 is installed Button enabled, if viewpager2 is not installed button false;

```
    List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ImageButton btn_down, btn_fav;
    private Button btn_setter;
    private DatabaseReference movies;
    private IFirebaseLoadDone iFirebaseLoadDone;

    public CartoonFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cartoon, container, false);

        movies = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Sports");
        movies.keepSynced(true);
        iFirebaseLoadDone = this;
        loadMovie();

        viewPager2 = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager2_);

        btn_down = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_down);
        btn_setter = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_setter);
        btn_fav = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_fav);


        btn_down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             SaveToGallery();
            }

        });

        btn_setter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }

        });
        btn_fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void loadMovie() {
        movies.addValueEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<Movie> movieList) {
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext(), movieList, viewPager2);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebasLoadFailed(String message) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot moviesSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            movieList.add(moviesSnapShot.getValue(Movie.class));
        Collections.reverse(movieList);
        iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(movieList);

        viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebasLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        movies.removeEventListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        movies.removeEventListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: please upload the code along with the question.

Comment: I added the codes. please help me

Comment: Jaymin are these enough?

Comment: Just disable the button in loadMovie and enable it when data is loaded.

Comment: can you show on the code?

Comment: I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your methods with mine.

```
private void loadMovie() {
        movies.addValueEventListener(this);
        btn_down.setEnabled(false);
        btn_fav.setEnabled(false);
        btn_setter.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

**Firebase methods**

```
@Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<Movie> movieList) {
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext(), movieList, viewPager2);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        if(movieList!=null && !movieList.isEmpty()){
            btn_down.setEnabled(true);
            btn_fav.setEnabled(true);
            btn_setter.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebasLoadFailed(String message) {
         btn_down.setEnabled(false);
        btn_fav.setEnabled(false);
        btn_setter.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error loading

```
private void loadMovie() {
        movies.addValueEventListener(this);
        btn_down.setEnabled(false);
        btn_fav.setEnabled(false);
        btn_setter.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.duvarlar.Fragment.CartoonFragment.loadMovie(CartoonFragment.java:386)
        at com.example.duvarlar.Fragment.CartoonFragment.onCreateView(CartoonFragment.java:90)
```